# Why do I get an "Invalid gadgets.rpc token" error when loading the Google+ JS client?

Tags: javascript, google-plus

I want to be able to make calls to Google+ in JS code such as this:

```
    gapi.client.plus.people.get({"userId": "me"});
```

In my HTML I'm loading the following JS sources:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[our maps api key]&sensor=true"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="biketracker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=onGoogleJsClientLoaded"></script>
```

In biketracker.js, I'm also doing an async load of the Google+ JS:

```
(function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
})();
```

The callback when the Google JS client source is loaded then loads three other Google APIs:

```
function onGoogleJsClientLoaded() {
    console.log("onGoogleJsClientLoaded()");

    gapi.client.load("biketracker", "v1", onBikeTrackerApiLoaded, endpointsRoot);
    gapi.client.load("oauth2", "v2", onOAuth2Loaded);
    gapi.client.load("plus", "v1", onGooglePlusClientLoaded);
}
```

The first of these is not really a Google API, but a Google Endpoints API we've developed, hosted on App Engine. Ignore it. OAuth2 loads just fine. The Plus API, however, gives me these errors:

```
Invalid gadgets.rpc token. 2006255737 vs 542328210
Uncaught Error: m`apiproxy6892d048ac55f727a04aed9791f4e586b15e69860.4984859501703547
```

I can find no-one else with the same errors. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using Google+ Sign-In, the +1 button, or the various badges? If you are not using these features (although you probably should if you have a social app) then you do not need plusone.js: the Google client library is what you need for API access and if gapi.client is defined, you should be able to load the Google+ client library without issue. To test this, you can see if gapi.client.plus... exists, and if it does, you have access to the Google+ endpoints!

If you ARE using Google+ Sign-In, you should not be performing an async load of the Google API script within your own JS modules. For reasons that go beyond the scope of this answer, some of the JavaScript code used by the JavaScript Google client libraries must be initialized globally. This is the second most likely cause of your error.

These errors may not be causing bugs on your site. The plusone.js script is used to render various widgets on the screen such as the Google+ Sign-In button and is the most likely culprit for the RPC errors you're encountering. Sometimes, the API can fail on first load and this is ok so long as the button is rendering as you expect.

You might be encountering a race condition where the client library or Google+ libraries are competing with each other. Try including client.js in addition to plusone.js your async load function and add your callback for when the scripts load:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
  var po = document.createElement('script');
  po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
  po.src = 'https://plus.google.com/js/client:plusone.js?onLoad=onGoogleJsClientLoaded';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
})();
```

Comment: Sir, you are a scholar and a gentleman. I had no idea you could load both sources using "client:plusone.js" (I am indeed using Google+ sign in) and no idea it was wrong to do the load in my own JS file rather than in an inline script in the HTML. Thank you.